# how to consume .net webservices

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services

please tell that can we consume .net web services in php or not.
if yes then please tell me how can we do it.

i am to create a web service which takes values and save it in database also it will take values and reply some data as a standard xml format.

i know how to create web service and how to use it in asp.net but don't know how to use/call it from php.
thing is that i will not be writing code in php to consume but wants to know that do i need to take care of any special thing or need to do some extra code to make it available and use by php developers.

i am to create web service in .net framework 2.0

Thanks

Comment: What kind of WebService is this? SOAP 2? you should be able to easily consume such a service.

Comment: @ZeissS: i am creating web service using visual studio 2005. so it will be that what default provided.

Comment: @ZeissS FYI in Micro$oft land, a "Web Service" means a SOAP service. I'm trying to port a REST app from PHP to .Net at the moment and have learned the hard way that they're decidedly anti-REST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but it looks like you have your work cut out for you. .Net web services are based on SOAP. The PHP class you're looking for is [SoapClient](http://au.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php).

Take some time to read through the PHP site's documentation. .Net hides a lot of the raw SOAP nuts and bolts, so you're going to need to peel back the curtain on your web service a bit.

One easy way is to play with an existing WS client through a proxy like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com), which lets you see exactly what's going back and forth.

Good luck,

n.

Comment: can you plez explain me it clear that the service created by me in .net(2.0) will be able to consumed by php developers or not.. please provide me more detail

Comment: Yes it will, because it's a SOAP service, it can be consumed in PHP using the SoapClient class as mentioned above. I can't really give more detail - the specifics depend entirely on the architecture of your application.